# How to access function in webpack from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I have some HTML code

```
<input onkeyup="searchJobsEn()" id="" type="text">
```

> [Webpack.js is included in page source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb0xI.png)

When I try execute p.ex. searchJobsEn() I am receiving error :

> admin:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: searchJobsEn is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (admin:18)

How to call this function in HTML?

Comment: Show your work. Indicate what you've found in the webpack documentation and why it isn't helpful. Indicate what you discovered when you googled that error message, and why it wasn't helpful. Strip your code down to the barest example that will run but still causes the error, and if it's not huge, post it in your question. See the forum guidelines on posting a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: do you have `<script src='path/to/bundle.js'></script>` in your html?

Comment: @EgorEgorov yes

Comment: @GreatBigBore I added screenshot with webpack script loaded as source. I can't find anything about it in Symfony documentation, I am doing this 1st time... Idk why those functions are not accesible from HTML.

Comment: You need to get it into the global scope; easiest is to put it on `window`, but I don't know if that's the cleanest way. We have packed stuff we use in non-React code that we hang on some namespaces off `window`; it works fine for us.

Comment: I tried make window.functionName = functionName(); but then functions are executed when page loads, not on event handler from HTML. @DaveNewton

Comment: `window.functionName = functionName`. Don't add the `()`, which will call the function and assign the result to `window.functionName`

Comment: @Questionnaire Don't forget google. I see a few hits from "webpack uncaught reference error". If those don't apply to your situation, explain why they were unhelpful (not to me; edit your question and add to it so everyone can understand more about your problem).

Comment: @GreatBigBore yeah, I googled 'function not defined webpack' but found reply window.functionName = functionName(), what I tried. HakenLid gave correct answer. Thanks for help.

Comment: Because you're calling it-what would you expect?!